# Create array of objects from hash keys and values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a collection of product codes in an array: `@codes`. I then check to see how many instances of each product I have:

```
@popular = Hash.new(0)

@codes.each do |v|
    @popular[v] += 1
end
```

This produces a hash like `{ code1 => 5, code2 => 12}`. What I really need is a nice array of the form:

```
[ {:code => code1, :frequency => 5}, {:code => code2, :frequency => 12} ]
```

How do I build an array like that from the hashes I'm producing? Alternatively, is there a more direct route? The objects in question are ActiveModel objects with `:code` as an attribute. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@popular.map { |k, v| { code: k, frequency: v } }
```

This will produce an array of `Hash`es. If you need an array of models, replace the inner `{...}` with an appropriate constructor.

Comment: FYI: This is providing the keys and values to the iterator

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
@codes.each_with_object([]) do
  |code, a|
  if h = a.find{|h| h[:code] == code}
    h[:frequency] += 1
  else
    a.push(code: code, frequency: 0)
  end
end
```

For speed:

```
@codes.group_by{|e| e}.map{|k, v| {code: k, frequency: v.length}}
```

Comment: I'd add a disclaimer that the two-step process is faster if `@codes` is of a significant length, since `Array#find` is not the sharpest tool in the shed.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but this is another way:

```
def counts(codes)
  codes.uniq.map { |e| { code: e, frequency: codes.count(e) } }
end

codes = %w{code5 code12 code5 code3 code5 code12 code7}
  #=> ["code5", "code12", "code5", "code3", "code5", "code12", "code7"]
counts(codes)
  #=> [{:code=>"code5", :frequency=>3}, {:code=>"code12", :frequency=>2},
  #    {:code=>"code3", :frequency=>1}, {:code=>"code7" , :frequency=>1}]
```